# How much mining before I achieve a coin?

Tags: openethereum

How much mining before I achieve a coin?
How long before I achieve one coin

Comment: I'd recommend to check your equipment with any online mining calculator. For mining related probably is better to ask at reddit.com/r/EtherMining.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on mostly two factors:

1. The amount of hashes your hardware can solve per time unit
2. The current network difficulty

The first factor is fully up to your hardware, so I can't comment on that. The second factor is currently 4,023,833,744,841,626 (https://www.coinwarz.com/mining/ethereum/difficulty-chart). The higher the number, the more difficult it is to mine a block. You can use various calculators to check profitability, for example here: https://badmofo.github.io/ethereum-mining-calculator/